# Convert separate 'year' and 'day' columns into one 'date' column with lubridate?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have one column for 'year' and one column for 'day' (julian day) and I want to use these columns to make a 'date' (2002-12-03 or any format is okay).  I've found a lot of `lubridate` literature on breaking up dates, but am looking for how to put them together.

As simple as it sounds:

```
year    day    
2008    1
2008    2
2008    3
2008    4
```

to

```
year    day    date
2008    1    2008-1-1
etc.
```

Comment: What would you do about month?

Comment: @iShouldUseAName It's a julian day, so it's 1-365.

Comment: The day column is Julian days, so it runs 1-365.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use base dates rather than lubridate if you like

If this is your sample data

```
dd<-data.frame(
    year = rep(2008,4), 
    day = 1:4
)
```

Then you can run

```
years <- unique(dd$year)
yearstarts <- setNames(as.Date(paste0(years, "-01-01")), years)
newdates <- yearstarts[as.character(dd$year)] + dd$day - 1
```

Which produces

```
cbind(dd, newdates)

#   year day   newdates
# 1 2008   1 2008-01-01
# 2 2008   2 2008-01-02
# 3 2008   3 2008-01-03
# 4 2008   4 2008-01-04
```

This works because the base Date class stores the number of days since a particular sentinel value. So you when you add 1, you are adding one day to the current date. Here I assumed you may have multiple years to I make sure to correctly calculate the Date value for the first day of each year.

Comment: this works great and looks like it covers leap years too.  I still get so confused thinking about how the Date class works that I am trying to move to `lubridate`.  I was afraid to ask this kind of question without the `lubridate` tag because I know the answer is probably out there, but with a lot of stuff to sort through that I don't really understand.